# How to solve DownloadManager status pending?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm trying to make a download file prosess in my android apps with `DownloadManager` class and put some `Toast` with the download status. When I click download button, the Toast always say that my download is pending. Why it happend?

In `DownloadManager` documnet I'd read that pending mean the download is waiting to start. What is waiting for? Where should I looking for? How do I change the status and start the download?

Here's my code :

```
public void downloadFile(){
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://kopi81.000webhostapp.com/cccc.jpg");
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                "cccc.jpg");
        Long ref = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterById(ref);
        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            DownloadStatus(cursor, ref);
        }
    }
```

I think my internet is also good no problem with it. The file that I'm trying to get is from my server on **000webhost.com**. When I try to get any file from another server the download's start. Is my server that got the problem or my android application?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this code for you. I hope to help you ❤ :

```java
private DownloadManager downloadManager;
private Uri Download_Uri;
private long refid;
```

```java
public void downloadFile(){

        registerReceiver(onComplete,
        new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Download_Uri = Uri.parse("https://kopi81.000webhostapp.com/cccc.jpg");
        DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
                req.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
                req.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
                req.setTitle("Downloading ... " );
                req.setDescription("Downloading " + "cccc.jpg");
                req.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
                req.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/Kopi81/"  + "cccc.jpg");
                refid = downloadManager.enqueue(req);

                }


    BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

               Toast.makeText(context,"Download completed !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Kopi81")
                .setContentText("Download completed !");
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(455, mBuilder.build());


        }
    };}
```

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I tested on my device [Sony Z3] & [Sony XZ] and had no problem !

good luck.